# Pandas return Empty Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets (Tweets and users). For the first one, I have found top 25 twitter users, and compiled them into a list. I want to match these users with my second data set and for python to return the row of information that matches each users, however when I try to iterate through the list it and locating the user it keeps on returning Empty Data frames.

What could be the problem?

```
import panda as pd
r=pd.read_csv("tweets.csv")
r.head()

u=pd.read_csv("users.csv") 


user_count = r.user_key.value_counts()
print(user_count)

top = user_count.head(25)
#print(top)

uc_d = dict(top)
#print(uc_d)

l=uc_d.keys()
#print(l)

l_top = list()
for t in uc_d.keys():
    l_top.append(t)
#print(l_top)


for x in l_top:
    print(u.loc[u['screen_name'] == 'x'])
```

in the for loop, id like python to go over the list of usernames (l_top) and for each name, find corresponding information in "users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line. Change

```
for x in l_top:
    print(u.loc[u['screen_name'] ==' x'])
```

to

```
for x in l_top:
    print(u.loc[u['screen_name'] == x])
```

Comment: Ah thanks! 
Did this, but it only returns information of 4 usernames, while I have 25 of them in the list I'm iterating through.

Comment: the rest of the results just print "Series([], Name: description, dtype: object)" without content

Comment: Is `u['screen_name']` similar to  `r['user_key']`? It might be the case that one of them is display names and the other is username or something like that. Hard to tell without looking at the data

Comment: User_key belongs to the first data set and screen_name to the second, but they both represent the twitter handle of said user!